# Effectiveness of my referring SO posts to DBA

Tags: support, migration, statistics

Quite often I select "this question belongs on DBA site" option for SO posts that ask about migrations, bulk loads, installations and such.

Is there an easy way to collect statistics how often these questions were in fact migrated as I suggested?

Comment: There's probably a SEDE query for it. There's a SEDE query for everything.

Comment: @Draco18s - How do I locate one like this?  Any pointers?

Comment: SEDE is a database, you can write a query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). It uses syntax that's very close (if not identical to) MySQL, and a schema is helpfully located on the right. I'm terrible at it though.

Comment: @Draco18s - the syntax is SQL Server - because it runs against SQL Server 2016

Comment: @MartinSmith I actually didn't know what SEDE's backend was, only that it was a database (and most database syntax looks very similiar to most other database syntax for those of us, such as myself, who know only enough to be dangerous)

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible as far as I can see. Successful migrations cause the post to be deleted on the source site, so the post disappears from the Data Export (and the Data Explorer). The post history on the target site of a successful migration does not include user IDs, so you cannot filter them on a specific user having participated.

Regardless, below are some queries that might help you anyway. For example, if you manually keep a list of questions you voted on to migrate, you can quickly compare it to the 'finding failed migrations' query below.

## Finding failed migrations

You can find some failed migrations with the following query, due to the posts not being deleted here when the migration never completes or is rejected. If the post is deleted afterwards, it also won't show up in the data explorer.

```sql
select
  ph.*
from
  Posts p
  inner join PostHistory ph on ph.PostId = p.Id
where
  ph.PostHistoryTypeId in (35) -- Post Migrated Away
  and ph.Comment like '%://dba.stackexchange.com%'
  and ph.Text like '%"Id":##UserId##,%'
```

## Finding successful migrations

Quite similar to the query above [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/779006/so-to-dba-se-migrations).

```sql
select
  ph.*, 
  so_id
from
  Posts p
  inner join PostHistory ph on ph.PostId = p.Id
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(ph.Comment, CHARINDEX('/questions/', ph.Comment) + LEN('/questions/'), 8000))) CA(id_first)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (LEFT(id_first,CHARINDEX('/',id_first) -1))) CA2(so_id)
where
  ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 36 -- Post Migrated Here
  and ph.Comment like '%://stackoverflow.com%'
```

Comment: Even when using posts_with_deleted or whatever it is named?

Comment: @TinyGiant Hmm, I'm not really sure what that table is. There doesn't seem to be a lot of information in it.

Comment: @TinyGiant - It contains the deleted posts but there is no way of knowing why they were deleted or who voted to close them.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MartinSmith